# Need Perl one-liner regex to get rid of the if condition syntax error from a shell script file

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I am getting a syntax error from my shell script file when I detect it using

```
sh -n test.sh

test.sh: line 255: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
test.sh: line 255: `      if [[ $type == "SA" ]] then'
test.sh: line 387: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
test.sh: line 387: `      if (( MM == 1 )) then'
```

Obviously this error is due to the misplaced `then` after the `if` condition, as it is present in the same line without `;`. This error is occurring at many places.

It would be very tedious to manually correct every line of code as this shell script contains nearly 1000 lines. So, in order to rectify the `if condition`, I have formulated this Perl command

```
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=\)) then/$1; then/' test.sh
perl -pi -e 's/(?<=\]) then/$1; then/' test.sh
```

I want to improve the above Perl one-liners by considering the following things

- I want to combine both substitutions to form a single command. That is, taking into account both 'if [[ ]]' and 'if (( ))' in the shell script
- There may be multiple spaces between the closing `)` or `]` and `then`
- There may be whitespace after `then`
- I need to either replace it with `;` or newline `"\n"` to fix this shell syntax error
- Are there any better method to solve this issue other than the one which I am using?

Comment: Another bug -- you're using `sh` to execute scripts that have extensions (such as `[[ ]]` and `(( ))`) present in `bash` but not in `sh`. Use bash to execute your scripts, or rewrite them to use only POSIX constructs, or you'll have additional non-syntax errors later.

Comment: It is a ksh script, and ideally I would check it by using: `sh -n`

Comment: That's not ideal at all; when you use `sh -n`, it has no knowledge of ksh extensions to syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `$1` as you are not capturing anything:

```
 's/(?<=\)) then/; then/'
```

Use `|` to introduce alternatives:

```
's/(?<=\)|\]) then/; then/'
```

Use `\s` to represent whitespace and the `+` quantifier to mark repetition:

```
's/(?<=\)|\])\s+then/; then/'
```

Use `/x` for readability:

```
's/ (?<= \) | \] ) \s+ then/; then/x'
```

Comment: I'd use `s/[)\]]\K(?= then)/;/` unless backwards compatibility with 5.8 is required.

Comment: @ikegami, you'd want `(?=\s+then)` to satisfy one of the question's requirements.

Comment: @ikegami, thanks for your comment, could you explain me this syntax? `'s/[)\]]\K(?=\s+then)/;/'`

Comment: `\K` causes what precedes it to not get replaced. More efficient than a lookbehind.